# How do I deserialize JSON with extra attributes in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, serialization, ruby-on-rails-4

I load some models using custom SQL `#find_by_sql` because vanilla Rails relationships were too slow, and the models automatically have the extra attribute fields. Serializing works fine. However, when I deserialize, it complains that there is an unknown attribute. I tried `without_protection` but it didn't help. How do I deserialize my model and keep the extra attributes?

```
> Post.new(JSON.parse(json), without_protection: true)
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute: username
```

I tried to add `attr_accessor` fields, and that works for deserializing the models, but then it doesn't work for serializing!

```
> p.username
=> nil
> p.read_attribute :username
=> "test30"
> p.to_json
=> "{\"id\":129,\"user_id\":32,\"title\":\"The weird...\",\"username\":null}"
```

Ruby 2.0.0, Rails 4.0.3.

Comment: Wouldn't adding `attr_accessor :username` to your model be enough?

Comment: Yes it would! I just did that and it worked then came back to update this post! You can have the answer if you want.

Comment: So this is resolved then?

Comment: @Wukerplank Not completely. I spoke too soon. Now `p.username` works, but `p.read_attribute(:username)` doesn't! `read_attribute` works when I use `find_by_sql`, but not when I add those `attr_accessors`. I use `read_attribute` to use the fast method if not null, and fall back to the slow relationships if it doesn't exist. I supposed I can just test the attribute directly now, instead of using `read_attribute`.

Comment: Yeah that isn't working now when I use the DB. I need to be able to read the value when parsed from JSON and also when loaded from the DB. `p.username || p.read_attribute(:username) || p.user.username` feels wrong. I think something's missing.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I experimented with attr_writer, attr_reader, virtual fields from methods, and found a workaround but I still don't think this is the best way.

In the model:

```
attr_accessor :username
# override to_json
  def to_json
    hash = self.as_json
    hash.merge!( {"username" => self.read_attribute(:username), 
       ... other fields ...
      } )
    hash.to_json
  end
```

However that causes nonsense like

```
> p = Post.loadFromDBviaFindBySQL.first
> p.username                                ### WTF?!
=> nil
> p.read_attribute :username
=> "starrychloe"
> json = p.to_json
=> "{\"id\":130,\"username\":\"starrychloe\" ... }"
> p1 = Post.new.from_json json
=> #<Post id: 130, ...>
> p1.username
=> "starrychloe"
> p1.read_attribute :username               ### WTF?!
=> nil
```

I have to use nonsense like this in my views

```
post.username || post.read_attribute(:username) || post.user.username
```